# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI… in DispatcherServlet with name

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

When performing a request to http://localhost:8080/SquirrelAuth/api/groups/.json I get this error:

Mar 24, 2015 5:55:52 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SquirrelAuth/api/groups/.json] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

I've been spinning on this one forever and can't seem to find any answers out there that work for me. Can anyone help me through this?

**Pom Dependencies/Properties**

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <oauth.version>2.0.7.RELEASE</oauth.version>
    <taglibs.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</taglibs.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
    <log4j.version>2.2</log4j.version>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    <jackson.version>2.5.1</jackson.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.6</mysql.version>
    <liquibase.version>3.3.2</liquibase.version>
    <javax.version>3.1.0</javax.version>
    <mavenWar.version>2.6</mavenWar.version>
    <mavenCompiler.version>3.2</mavenCompiler.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>${oauth.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${taglibs.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Web Application Intializer**

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {          
        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));    

        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));  
        servlet.addMapping("/");  
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);  

    }  

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("com.squirrels.config");
        return context;
    }

}
```

**PersistenceJPAConfig**

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.squirrels.controller", "com.squirrels.services", "com.squirrels.persistence.dao" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:squirrel.properties" })
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource());
        liquibase.setDefaultSchema(environment.getRequiredProperty("db_schema"));
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml");

        return liquibase;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.squirrels.persistence.model" });

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("db_driverClass"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("db_jdbcUrl"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("db_user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("db_password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("db_hibernateDialect"));
        return properties;
    }
}
```

**Groups Controller**

```
package com.squirrels.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.squirrels.dto.GroupDTO;
import com.squirrels.services.GroupUtil;

@Controller
public class GroupsController {

    @Autowired
    GroupUtil groupUtil;

    static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(GroupsController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/groups/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<GroupDTO> getGroups() {

        List<GroupDTO> groupList = null;
        try {
            groupList = groupUtil.getAll();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return groupList;
    }
}
```

**WebMvcConfig**

```
package com.squirrels.config;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ContentNegotiationConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    /*
     * Configure ContentNegotiationManager
     */
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.ignoreAcceptHeader(true).defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    }

    /*
     * Configure ContentNegotiatingViewResolver
     */
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager) {
        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
        resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);

        // Define all possible view resolvers
        List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<ViewResolver>();
        resolvers.add(jsonViewResolver());         
        resolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
        return resolver;
    }

    /*
     * Configure View resolver to provide JSON output using JACKSON library to
     * convert object in JSON format.
     */
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver jsonViewResolver() {
        return new JsonViewResolver();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it finally last night.

I added this to the WebMvcConfig class and all is well.

```
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` that spring uses to resolve @RequestMapping annotations has a property `alwaysUseFullPath` which defaults to false.  This means that the mappings you set on handlers (i.e. your @RequestMapping annotations) are resolved relative to the dispatcher servlet mapping which in your case is `/api` .

Seems that you have not overriden it so make the base mapping path of the controller `/groups` instead of `/api/groups`

see [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping) for details

Comment: Added this bean to the persistence config and still get the same error.

 @Bean
 public RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping(){
  RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
  handlerMapping.setAlwaysUseFullPath(true);  
  return handlerMapping;
 }

Comment: Im not sure the /.json path works correctly according to this http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-suffix-pattern-match Try to experiment a bit by adding something before the .json let's say /abc.json and adjusting the mapping to /abc

Comment: Updated my classes in my question to reflect changes from your suggestions. Got rid of the .json entirely.